# Error In Wordpress Cpanel

Tags: cpanel

I am having this error in my website url

```
Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /home/shri33c5/public_html/wp-includes/l10n.php:1) in /home/shri33c5/public_html/wp-content/themes/dirte/functions.php on line 19
```

and

```
Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/shri33c5/public_html/wp-includes/l10n.php:1) in /home/shri33c5/public_html/wp-content/themes/dirte/functions.php on line 19
```

Can anyone please tell me the fix.

Comment: Too many question about this. File /home/shri33c5/public_html/wp-includes/l10n.php ?? What is his content (Almost line1)?

Comment: Upload your WordPress files/folders and theme again. This should fix the problem. There should be unwanted whitespace in on of the file which is causing this issue.

Comment: thanks for the reply i have fixed the problem.